# Crossfilter.js group by multiple categorical axis

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter, categorical-data

I have the following problem:
My dataset looks as follows:

```
[{
"id": 1542284,
"date": "2013-04-22",
"kilometer": 111179.364089776,
"country": "RU",
"ps": 100,
"model": "110A"
},
{
"id": 1542285,
"date": "2013-08-30",
"kilometer": 211963.649155722,
"country": "FR",
"ps": 110
"model": "110A"
},
{
"id": 1542286,
"date": "2013-03-07",
"kilometer": 163694.246231156,
"country": "DE",
"ps": 120
"model": "210B"}]
```

now I want to use dc.js together with crossfilter.js to make a HEATMAP with the 
x axis: country and the 
y axis: model.
The color attribute would be corresponding to the number of items in the group: |(country x model)|

***My question is now how to make the crossfilter.js group statement with two categorical axis?!***

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var countryDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d){
    return d.country;
});

modelByCountryGroup = countryDimension.group().reduce(
    /* callback for when data is added to the current filter results */
    function (p, v) {
        ++p.count;
        //HOW DO I STORE/PROCESS v.model HERE
        return p;
    },
    /* callback for when data is removed from the current filter results */
    function (p, v) {
        --p.count;
        //HOW DO I STORE/PROCESS v.model HERE
        return p;
    },
    /* initialize p */
    function () {
        return {count: 0, WHATDOINEEDHERE};
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you create a combined dimension?

```
var dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.country + ":" + d.model; });
var group = dim.group();
```

This will give you your counts by country x model, right?

Comment: @ethan: This is really nice :)

Comment: @anmolkoul It's easy in this situation because the country codes are fixed length. If there are variable lengths and/or we can't guarantee the separator doesn't appear in the value, then we start to have trouble.